# Opencart 3 Error: A theme has not been assigned to this store!

Tags: opencart3.x

В Opencart 3 не применяется тема, сам движок свежий без изменений, тема под 3 версию, установил запись для администратора на все файлы (галочки). Работаю на Openserver.

Error: A theme has not been assigned to this store!

в логах есть такая ошибка
FILE: catalog/view/theme/listore/template/information/contact.twig
CODE: {{ column_left }}
NOT FOUND - OPERATIONS ABORTED!

С другими темами тоже  column_left как ошибка

Comment: модули/расширения - темы. там тема включена?

Comment: Да, включил, все уже включил. Не пойму почему не работает